# Removing custom pagination and using jetpack infinite scroll

Tags: wordpress, pagination, infinite-scroll

I've followed the Jetpack Infinite scroll instructions for custom themes and still it doesn't work!

I've found a pagination.php in theme/framework/functions/pagination.php and I don't know if this is taking over or making it not work.

This is the pagination code

```
<?php
//custom pagination function
function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4) {
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;
 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '') {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages) {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }  

 if(1 != $pages) {
     echo "<div class=\"page-pagination\"><div class=\"page-pagination-inner clearfix\">";
     echo "<div class=\"page-of-page\"><span class=\"inner\">".$paged." of ".$pages."</span></div>";
     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current outer\"><span class=\"inner\">".$i."</span></span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\"><span class=\"inner\">".$i."</span></a>";
         }
     }
      echo "</div></div>\n";
 }
} // end pagination()
?>
```

should i delete it with the function to get infinite scroll working?